# Horizontal Rule in Content Editor Web Part?

Tags: content-editor-web-part, cewp

When editing rich text in a CEWP, as typical not-admin user, how does one go about inserting a horizontal rule? Google has not been my friend. I'm loathe to tell the users they need to edit the HTML and stuff in an HR tag. And I'm hoping there is a better answer than that or, even worse, a giant string of underscore characters. This would be for SP2010 Server, if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about you guys but on my CEWP if I do the following, I can enter an HR tag without moving to the html view:

- Type some dummy text
- Click the area where we want the line
- In the ribbon, pick Editing Tools > Format Text > **Markup Styles** > Horizontal Rule

We can even customize the look and feel of the line with CSS using

**hr.ms-rteElement-Hr**

**update:** screenshot (specific of SharePoint 2010)

[image]

In SharePoint 2013, we can create new elements through CSS, e.g.

```
/*extensions*/
/*page elements*/
span.ms-rteElement-CustomHRElement{
    -ms-name:"HR in page elements";
    background-color: #b6b6b6;
    height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
/*text styles*/
.ms-rteStyle-CustomHRStyle{
    -ms-name:"HR in text styles";
    background-color: #b6b6b6;
    height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed. If it was a snake, I surely would have gotten bit. Just didn't see it there amongst the other choices. Thank you sir.

Comment: I have SP2013 and I can not locate the horizontal rule. Appreciate if you can post a screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: @Aslan this solution is specific of SP2010. but there's always the possibility of editing the source and adding "<hr/>"