# How to add a divider line between two web parts?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, web-part

I want to add a horizontal dark line underneath my web parts to separate each. How do I need to go about doing this?

Comment: Modern UI or Classic UI? Out of the box web parts, or custom web parts?

Answer (score 2):

If it is modern page (site page), you can use [Divider web part](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/add-a-line-between-web-parts-with-the-divider-web-part-7204a0fa-f0c2-4f1e-8e7b-d0ebd4276ad4) to add a line between web parts.

[image]

If it is a classic page, you can add a Script Editor web part between the web parts and enter html such as `<hr/>` in a Script Editor web part as horizontal line.

Or, create the custom text style with the following scripts as horizontal line.

```
/*extensions*/
/*page elements*/
span.ms-rteElement-CustomHRElement{
    -ms-name:"HR in page elements";
    background-color: #b6b6b6;
    height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
/*text styles*/
.ms-rteStyle-CustomHRStyle{
    -ms-name:"HR in text styles";
    background-color: #b6b6b6;
    height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Refer to [Horizontal Rule in Content Editor Web Part?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103833/horizontal-rule-in-content-editor-web-part) for more information.